# comparing variables in bash script using if statements

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

So I'm pretty new to bash scripting but so far tldp.org has been a good friend. Anyways I've confused myself and swearing to much so looking for help in clarification: I declare a variable like such
    MAXseeds=-1;
    sumS=0
I do a bunch of things in my script and get a new value for sumS which is an integer value. I would then like to compare MAXseeds and sumS if sumS is larger make MAXseeds equal to sumS. I do this by:

```
  echo $MAXseeds      
  echo $sumS    
  if [ $MAXseeds -lt $sumS ];
  then 
     MAXseeds = $sumS
     best_file=$COUNT
  fi 
  echo $MAXseeds
```

This from what I can tell should work however the terminal output I get when running over this section of script is

```
  -1
  492
  lookup.sh: line 34: MAXseeds: command not found
  -1
```

Basically I am wondering what I am doing wrong here? why does it respond with command not found? Any explanation to why this is incorrect would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't destroy the question by removing the flaw.  Give the guy who answered you the accept and maybe an up-vote too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if [ $MAXseeds -lt $sumS ];
then 
  MAXseeds=$sumS
  best_file=$COUNT
fi
```

Without the spaces around "=".

If you put a space after "MAXseeds", then it will be interpreted as a command. And of course, it is not a command, thus you get your error message.

Comment: hey sorry although you would be correct this is not the problem the if statement is line 34, I did not copy that bit from my code correctly there is no spaces around "=". I have updated question to reflect this as well. My script is trying to evaluate $MAXseeds as a command not a variable why is this?

Comment: @brendanmorrison: you don't show line 34; you can't expect us to debug line 34.  Show us the SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) version of your problem.  Don't invalidate the answers that have been given.  Don't expect us to work miracles — we can't debug what you don't show!

Comment: will do Jonathan, I thought editing would be simpler none the less i will add to my question and outline my exact problem as clearly what I have above should work